# Convert MySql query in JPA Spring Boot query

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, join

I have this query, working, but I should use it in spring boot,

```
SELECT username
FROM user
WHERE enabled = 1 
AND id IN (SELECT makerprofile_user_id
           FROM makerprofile_has_job
           WHERE job_id = (SELECT id
                           FROM job
                           WHERE job = "photographer"))
```

This is the part of the Job class

```
@JoinTable(name = "makerprofile_has_job", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "job_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "makerprofile_user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")})
    @ManyToMany
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Makerprofile> makerprofileList;
```

and I write this, but it does not work

```
@Query("SELECT a.username\n"
            + "FROM ApplicationUser a \n"
            + "WHERE a.enabled = 1 \n"
            + "AND a.id IN(SELECT p.id\n"
            + "        FROM Job m\n"
            + "        JOIN m.makerprofileList p"
            + "            WHERE p.id = (SELECT j.id\n"
            + "              FROM Job j\n"
            + "              WHERE j.job = :job))")
    List<String> findUsernameByJob(@Param("job") String job);
```

who can help me? (excuse me, but this is my first question on Stack)

Comment: Are you using JPA repository interfaces?

Comment: What does "but it does not work" mean? Is there any error message given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the following ways:

1. Use `EntityManager.createNativeQuery()` API
2. Use `@NamedNativeQuery annotation`. Or `@Query(value = "sql here", nativeQuery = true)`